# Flutter: import package only for web users

Tags: flutter

I see that Flutter has conditional import statements, but after looking at some examples I’m still confused.

If I want to have main.dart import package “package:xyz/xyz.dart” only when the user is on web, how can I achieve that in the simplest way? Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 4):

We could import a package only for the web users by the use of a conditional import:

```
import 'package:xyz/mobile.dart' 
    if (dart.library.html) 'package:xyz/web.dart';
```

The code above imports `package:xyz/web.dart` only if `dart.library.html` is available, which happens to be the case for the web platform.